# Slicing data frames .loc issue

Tags: python, dataframe, anaconda

I don't see how I have an error here... I have tried adding ".loc" but it keeps giving this error:

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing
>   imports until

This is the code:

```
valid['Predictions'] = 0
valid['Predictions'] = preds

valid.index = new_data[4780:].index
train.index = new_data[:4780].index
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: `new_data.iloc[:,4780:]`?

Comment: `valid.loc[:,'Predictions'] = preds`?

Comment: This is my error: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. Check out the pandas documentation the link is pointing to. It should clarify the reason why it gives this warning.

Comment: Yeah I saw that... unfortunately I could not find a suitable place to put .loc without it giving me an error.